# Remove "Checkout is not available whilst your cart is empty." notice in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout, notice

What code should I add to `functions.php` to remove "Checkout is not available whilst your cart is empty." notice in Woocommerce.

I found the code in [includes/wc-template-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0a857088f994def1aca6f3feb3e4a4af964b225f/includes/wc-template-functions.php) that is responsible for displaying this message.

```php
// When on the checkout with an empty cart, redirect to cart page.
if ( is_page( wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) ) && wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) !== wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) && WC()->cart->is_empty() && empty( $wp->query_vars['order-pay'] ) && ! isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) && ! is_customize_preview() && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_redirect_empty_cart', true ) ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Checkout is not available whilst your cart is empty.', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' );
    wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_cart_url() );
    exit;

}
```

Overwriting the core file is NOT an option, any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_checkout_redirect_empty_cart` filter hook. Since the message is only displayed if this condition is true

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_redirect_empty_cart', '__return_false' );
```

---

Another option is to use the `woocommerce_add_notice` filter hook and if the message matches, return false

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_notice ( $message ) {
    // Equal to (Must be exactly the same).
    // If the message is displayed in another language, adjust where necessary!
    if ( $message == 'Checkout is not available whilst your cart is empty.' ) {
        return false;
    }   
    
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_notice', 'filter_woocommerce_add_notice', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Although the first way caused problems, the second solution is the most correct for me